# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined angular js client

Tags: javascript, angular, rest

I have a  Web Api  it returns a following json .

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "body": "This is my first Tweet",
    "author": "Kumar",
    "date": "2017-07-11T00:00:00+05:30",
    "retweets": [
      "Mahela",
      "Sanath"
    ],
    "favorites": [
      "Sanath"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "body": "This is my first Tweet",
    "author": "Virat",
    "date": "2017-07-11T00:00:00+05:30",
    "retweets": [
      "Mahela",
      "Sanath"
    ],
    "favorites": [
      "Sanath"
    ]
  }
]
```

I have  a Angular.js  client , after receiving the request i m getting 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined 'error from   **for(let tweet of resp.json().data)** belongs to following method .

```
getCurrentFeed() :Observable<Tweet[]>{


  return this.http.get('/GetTweets').map((resp :Response)=>{


    console.log(resp.json());

    var fetchedTweets=[];

    for(let tweet of resp.json().data)
    {
     fetchedTweets.push(this.getTweetFromJson(tweet));

    }
    return fetchedTweets as Array<Tweet>;
});

}
```

tweet.ts  is below

```
export class Tweet {

public avatar;



constructor( public id :number ,public body :string ,public author :string,public date:Date,public retweets:Array<string>,public favorites:Array<string>)
{
 this.avatar=`${author}.jpg`;

}
 }
```

Comment: `resp.json()` is the array, why are you expecting a `data` property?

Comment: `resp.json()` returns a promise that you have to `then` off of.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the data   from

```
for(let tweet of resp.json().data)
{
 fetchedTweets.push(this.getTweetFromJson(tweet));

}
```

fixed my issue